# Laravel Notifications pass variable from template to published vendor template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I've been building a mail template based on the published files you get from `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications`

And I've successfully edited the message layout to include a powered-by message, however this piece does not use a variable.

Now I'm stuck trying to add a unique unsubscribe url to just above (see picture below) this powered-by but I'm unable to pass it "upwards" to the vendor template `message.blade.php`

This is part is from my `toMail()` function from the Notification which is ultimately called by a `$user->notify(new Reminder(..))` function

```
return (new MailMessage())
    ->markdown('emails.reminder', ['unsubscribe_url' => 'custom_url_here'])
```

This is the editted `message.blade.php` file

```
<x-mail::layout>

{{-- Body --}}
{{ $slot }}

{{-- Subcopy --}}
@isset($subcopy)
<x-slot:subcopy>
    <x-mail::subcopy>
        {{ $subcopy }}
    </x-mail::subcopy>
</x-slot:subcopy>
@endisset

{{-- Footer --}}
<x-slot:footer>

    <x-mail::footer>
        <a href="{{ $unsubscribe_url }}">Unsubscribe here.</a>
    </x-mail::footer>

    <x-mail::powered-by />

    <x-mail::footer>
        © {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name') }}. @lang('All rights reserved.')
    </x-mail::footer>
</x-slot:footer>
</x-mail::layout>
```

I've tried to use functions like extends, yield, include, ... inside the `emails.reminder` blade template

Also tried different ways of adressing the vendor template to no luck.

```
@extends('vendor.mail.html.message',[
    'unsubscribe_url' => $unsubscribe_url,
])

@yield('vendor.mail.html.message',[
    'unsubscribe_url' => $unsubscribe_url,
])

@include('vendor.mail.html.message',[
    'unsubscribe_url' => $unsubscribe_url,
])

@extends('x-mail::message',[
    'unsubscribe_url' => $unsubscribe_url,
])

@extends('x-slot:message',[
    'unsubscribe_url' => $unsubscribe_url,
])

@extends('x-mail::footer',[
    'unsubscribe_url' => $unsubscribe_url,
])

@extends('x-slot:footer',[
    'unsubscribe_url' => $unsubscribe_url,
])

@extends('mail::html.message',[
    'unsubscribe_url' => $unsubscribe_url,
])

@extends('mail::text.message',[
    'unsubscribe_url' => $unsubscribe_url,
])
```

The picture as mentioned above:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making it much more difficult than it had to be because I didn't quite understand mails and templates.

The way you "pass variables to a higher laying template" in this case `message.blade.php` is just by **defining an extra region** where your text from the template you are using is pasted into.

```
<!-- message.blade.php -->

<x-mail::layout>
    @isset($foo) // if the section is optional
        <x-mail::foo>
            {{ $foo }}
        </x-mail::foo>
    @endisset
</x-mail::layout>
```

And define this slot in the template you are using by refering to `slot:foo` add passing which ever data you want to add there, in this case the unsubscribe url.

```
<!-- reminder.blade.php -->

<x-mail::message>
    <x-slot:foo>
        <a href="{{ $unsubscribe_url }}">Unsubscribe here.</a>
    </x-slot:foo>
</x-mail::message>
```

It's also required that if you add a new region you have to add this file `foo.blade.php` to the `mail/html` and `mail/text` folders